# Executing "make" command = no rule for target 'modules'

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, deepin

I am compiling a driver for mt7601U on my machine with Manjaro 17.1.2 - Deepin 15.

The instructions for compiling the driver can be found [here](https://github.com/kuba-moo/mt7601u/issues/64#issuecomment-352250127). I have done all the necessary commenting for the code. When I try to execute the command:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
```

It responded:

```
make: Entering directory '/usr/lib/modules/4.14.14-1-MANJARO/build'
make: *** No rule to make target 'modules'. Stop
make: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/modules/4.14.14-1-MANJARO/build'
```

Do I need another package to compile the driver correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, `/lib/modules/*/build` (where * is a versioning formatting of some sort) is a soft link to the Linux kernel header files to help build packages. The actual files being linked to are commonly found in `/usr/src/linux-*` (where * is again a versioning format).

It seems that you are on Linux 4.14. You should first verify that by running `uname -r` to double check the version. If so, you can install the header files by running the following:

```
$ sudo pacman -S linux414-headers
```

You may also want to update your system using:

```
$ sudo pacman-mirrors -f 5 && sudo pacman -Syyu
```

Then, reboot your system.